# CartoCSS detect odd vs even for use in labeling conditional

Tags: tilemill, mapbox, cartocss

I liked [the part in the advanced label styling](https://www.mapbox.com/tilemill/docs/guides/labels-advanced/#improved_direction_distribution_random_approach) about randomly asigning a 0 or 1 to control label placement and then using as a conditional

```
#labels {
  text-name: "[name]";
  text-face-name: "OpenSans Regular";
  text-placement-type: simple;
  text-placements: "E,NE,SE,W,NW,SW";
  [dir=1] { text-placements: "W,NW,SW,E,NE,SE"; }
}
```

Rather than create a new variable, could I just use my FID and detect whether or not it is odd/even? Is there a way to detect this property in the CartoCSS?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is possible if the ID is exposed as a regular data column, but CartoCSS has no way to access any internal ID stucture a particular data format might make use of.

If you have an appropriate column to filter on, you can then use a [regular expression filter](https://www.mapbox.com/tilemill/docs/guides/selectors/#regular_expression_filters) to divide up the features. Eg:

```
#labels {
  text-name: "[name]";
  text-face-name: "OpenSans Regular";
  text-placement-type: simple;
  text-placements: "E,NE,SE,W,NW,SW";
  [ID=~'.*[02468]$'] { text-placements: "W,NW,SW,E,NE,SE"; }
}
```

The nested filter checks if the last character of the id is an even digit (which will therefore mean the whole number is even) and alters the text-placements for them.